# Make a specific post category show in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, posts

I  am trying to run a loop that queries only a specific category from my wordpress. this is what i have but it shows all of my post instead of just my post under the category of 'testimonials'

```
    <div class="row">
          <?php if (is_page()) {
            $cat=get_cat_ID($post->post_title); //use page title to get a category ID
            $posts = get_posts ('cat=$cat&showposts=5');
            if ($posts) {
              foreach ($posts as $post):
                setup_postdata($post); ?>

                  <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <div class="box" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal1">
                      <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
                      <?php the_content(); ?>
                    </div>
                  </div>

              <?php endforeach;
            }
          }?>
      </div>
```

Please any help would be great,
thnx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thats because the arguments sent to `get_posts` isnt correct. Try:

```
$posts = get_posts(array(
    'category'=>$cat,
    'posts_per_page'=>5, //This changes how many posts are returned
    'offset' => 0, //This changes where it search starts from
);
```

Have a look at the [documentation here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts)

There is also a better way to get the post category:

```
$cat = get_the_category();
```

You dont have to pass the post ID to it because it will default to the current `$post->ID`.
You can checkout that [documentation here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_category)

Its also probably a bad idea to use `$post` in your foreach loop as that will overwrite the `global $post` variable. You may want to use something like `$curPost`